# Use local variable outside the function with dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to use "docid" outside the function how to do it ?

```
  getC() async {
    Usersref.where("email", isEqualTo: widget.list['email'])
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
        print(document.id);
        final docid = document.id;
        
      });
      
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<List<String>>getC() async {
List<String> idList=[];
await Usersref.where("email", isEqualTo: widget.list['email'])
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    print(document.id);
    idList.add( document.id);
    
  });
  
});
return idList;
}
```

Comment: thank you but how i can  access to idList outside  the function ??? when i do this : print(getC()); that's what the terminal shows Instance of 'Future<List<String>>' .. !!!

Comment: thank you sire that works good i just add await to the call !

Comment: You're most welcome, yes you have to await for future to complete. Happy coding :)